# wordpress add shortcode for a custom template

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Would be possible to add a short code to a custom template to can be included in articles?

```
lets say I have a page.example.php custom template
```

What I want to create a plugin what would return this template when the shortcode is included in Article.

```
function get_Example_Template() {

        $shortcode_content=get_template_part('page','example')
    return $shortcode_content;
}

add_shortcode( 'shortcode_content', 'get_Example_Template');
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking or what problems are you having? The code that you included looks like it's already headed in the right direction.

Comment: whit this codes I'm facing n infinite loop and it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable in your plugin that is initialized to false. The first time your function is called, set it to true. Each time the function is called, you'll only proceed if that variable is false.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is found here: [Calling WordPress get_template_part from inside a shortcode function renders template first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325348/calling-wordpress-get-template-part-from-insde-a-shortcode-function-renders-temp)

The issue is that get_template_part immediately echoes, and shortcodes need a return. Output buffering should solve the issue.