# Calling WordPress get_template_part from inside a shortcode function renders template first

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have a page where I need to allow the user to enter a paragraph of text. Then after that text, insert a shortcode that will render a list of posts, then add more free-form text after that. My thought was that they should be able to insert a shortcode which will output the posts. This way they can simply add the shortcode where they wish the posts to appear.

I currently have the logic which retrieve the posts separated in its own file. Currently I include it in a page by simply using the `get_template_part()` function:

```
get_template_part('donation', 'posts');
```

I looked into how to create a shortcode and included the following code into my `functions.php` file in order to create the shortcode:

```
add_shortcode('donation-posts', 'fnDonatePosts');   
function fnDonatePosts($attr, $content)
{
    get_template_part('donation', 'posts');    
}
```

The `donation-posts.php` is being properly executed and the posts are appearing, however, they are always positioned BEFORE the content and not in the location that the shortcode was placed.

I have tried removing the `get_template_part()` function and just output some text and that works fine. So I understand that the `get_template_part()` may not be the right way to do this, however, I have not been able to uncover a way to do what I am attempting to do (I am sure that there is a way... I just haven't found it).

I have tried:

```
include(get_template_directory(). '/donation-posts.php');
include_once(get_template_directory(). '/donation-posts.php') :
```

But these stopped processing once they hit the PHP code in the included file.

I have also tried:

```
$file = file_get_contents(get_template_directory(). '/donation-posts.php');  
        return $file;
```

But this only returns the contents of the file (as the function name indicates) which means it doesn't *execute* the PHP script to return the posts.

Anybody out there done this before?

Comment: Hopefully, this example is helpful too: https://wpza.net/using-get_template_part-in-a-shortcode/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You may try this, it may solve your problem because `get_template_part` basically reacts like `PHP's` `require`, it doesn't return but echos the content immediately where it's been called.

```
add_shortcode('donation-posts', 'fnDonatePosts');   
function fnDonatePosts($attr, $content)
{        
    ob_start();  
    get_template_part('donation', 'posts');  
    $ret = ob_get_contents();  
    ob_end_clean();  
    return $ret;    
}
```

Comment: Sorry it took so long for me to respond but I havea  ton of projects on my plate and this is a Pro-Bono project so it sits accordingly in the priorities. Anyway, your fix was just what I needed! Thank you!

Comment: it's such an ugly solution but it's the best (only?) one.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a more dynamic version where you can pass the path to the template.

```
function template_part( $atts, $content = null ){
   $tp_atts = shortcode_atts(array( 
      'path' =>  null,
   ), $atts);         
   ob_start();  
   get_template_part($tp_atts['path']);  
   $ret = ob_get_contents();  
   ob_end_clean();  
   return $ret;    
}
add_shortcode('template_part', 'template_part');
```

And the shortcode:

```
[template_part path="includes/social-sharing"]
```

Comment: Brilliant, despite SO telling me that comments are not here for *thank you* phrases I can only say, thank you, great modularity!

Answer (score 1):

Minimal version of the accepted answer:

```
function my_template_part_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    get_template_part( 'my_template' );
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'my_template_part', 'my_template_part_shortcode' );
```

where `my-template.php` is the file you'd like to include.

Answer (score 1):

get_template_part() didn't work for me when using it in functions.php. I used locate_template() inside the ob_start and clean instead. For example:

```
function full_petition_shortcode( $attr ) {
    ob_start();
    locate_template( 'petition.php', TRUE, TRUE );

    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'full-petition', 'full_petition_shortcode' );
```