# Place IF ELSE statement inside Woocommerce product loop - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, arguments, hook-woocommerce

I've got the following custom shortcode to display a range of products

```
add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode_name', 'on_sale_products' );

function on_sale_products() {
global $product, $woocommerce, $woocommerce_loop;

$args = apply_filters('woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
       // this is working array, just empty for this example
       ) 
);
$products = new WP_Query( $args );

ob_start();

woocommerce_product_loop_start();

while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post();

wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); 

endwhile; 

woocommerce_product_loop_end();

woocommerce_reset_loop();
wp_reset_postdata();

return '<div class="on-sale">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
}
```

I am trying to add a text message inside the loop that will say "No products to display" if there no products to show.

I'm struggling to correctly place the statement without getting a syntax error.

I've been fiddling around with the code like this:

```
add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode_name', 'on_sale_products' );

function on_sale_products() {
global $product, $woocommerce, $woocommerce_loop;

$args = apply_filters('woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
       // this is working array, just empty for this example
       ) 
);
$products = new WP_Query( $args );

ob_start();

woocommerce_product_loop_start();

if ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post() {

   wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); 

} else {

   echo '<div class="no-products">There are no products to display</div>';
} 

woocommerce_product_loop_end();

woocommerce_reset_loop();
wp_reset_postdata();

return '<div class="on-sale">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
}
```

But that's not correct.

Could you please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**2 things:**

1) You have removed the **while loop**. 
2) There is **an error** in this line:

```
if ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post() {
```

It should be instead *(in your code)*:

```
if ( $products->have_posts() ) { 
    $products->the_post();
```

---

So the following code, should be the correct way to get this working:

```
add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode_name', 'on_sale_products' );
function on_sale_products() {
    global $product, $woocommerce, $woocommerce_loop;

    $products = new WP_Query( apply_filters('woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
       // this is working array, just empty for this example
    ) ) );

    ob_start();
    woocommerce_product_loop_start();

    if ( $products->have_posts() ):
        while ( $products->have_posts() ): 
           $products->the_post();
           wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); 
        endwhile;
    else:
        echo '<div class="no-products">There are no products to display</div>';
    endif; 

    woocommerce_product_loop_end();
    woocommerce_reset_loop();
    wp_reset_postdata();

    return '<div class="on-sale">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This should work for you now…

Answer (score 0):

Try this example,

```
function newsItems( $atts ) {
$news_query= null;
$args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'news',
  'post_status'    => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 10,
);

$news_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$output = '';
if ( $news_query->have_posts() ) {
  $output .= '<div class="news-shortcode-posts">';
  while ( $news_query->have_posts() ) : $news_query->the_post();
      ob_start();
      get_template_part( 'inc/news-item' );
      $output .= ob_get_clean();
  endwhile;
  if( $show_archive == 'true' ) {
      $output .= '<div class="full-width align-right">';
      $output .= 'See All Archives';
      $output .= '</div>';
  }
  $output .= '</div>';
  }
  return $output;
}
add_shortcode('teamsters-news', 'newsItems');
```

Hope this will helps you. for more information.

- [Using WordPress get_template_part in Shortcode Loop](https://whiteleydesigns.com/using-get_template_part-shortcode-loop/)
- [get_template_part from inside a shortcode function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325348/calling-wordpress-get-template-part-from-inside-a-shortcode-function-renders-tem)